# failed to convert java.lang.String to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-03-15 12:25:37.668 ERROR 13724 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'spring.jackson.mapper' to java.util.Map<com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature, java.lang.Boolean>:

    Reason: failed to convert java.lang.String to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature (caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature.default-view-inclusions)

Action:

Update your application's configuration. The following values are valid:

    ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_ENUMS
    ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES
    ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_VALUES
    ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS
    ALLOW_EXPLICIT_PROPERTY_RENAMING
    ALLOW_FINAL_FIELDS_AS_MUTATORS
    ALLOW_VOID_VALUED_PROPERTIES
    APPLY_DEFAULT_VALUES
    AUTO_DETECT_CREATORS
    AUTO_DETECT_FIELDS
    AUTO_DETECT_GETTERS
    AUTO_DETECT_IS_GETTERS
    AUTO_DETECT_SETTERS
    BLOCK_UNSAFE_POLYMORPHIC_BASE_TYPES
    CAN_OVERRIDE_ACCESS_MODIFIERS
    DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION
    IGNORE_DUPLICATE_MODULE_REGISTRATIONS
    IGNORE_MERGE_FOR_UNMERGEABLE
    INFER_BUILDER_TYPE_BINDINGS
    INFER_CREATOR_FROM_CONSTRUCTOR_PROPERTIES
    INFER_PROPERTY_MUTATORS
    OVERRIDE_PUBLIC_ACCESS_MODIFIERS
    PROPAGATE_TRANSIENT_MARKER
    REQUIRE_SETTERS_FOR_GETTERS
    SORT_CREATOR_PROPERTIES_FIRST
    SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY
    USE_ANNOTATIONS
    USE_BASE_TYPE_AS_DEFAULT_IMPL
```

**application.properties**

```
# database configuration part
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:<portname>;dataName=<dbname>
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=5
spring.datasource.connectionTimeout=3600000
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=120000
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true



spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=false

# hibernate settings
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jackson.mapper.default-view-inclusions=true
```

how can i resolve this error please help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have a typo in the name of the Jackson mapper property:

```
spring.jackson.mapper.default-view-inclusions=true
```

It should be "inclusion", not "inclusions":

```
spring.jackson.mapper.default-view-inclusion=true
```